# Can't access process.env values using dynamic keys in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Can't access process.env values using dynamic keys**

.env file

TEST_ENV="www.test.com";
TEST_ENV_1 = "www.qwerrt.com";

.js

if am trying with directly process.env.TEST_ENV, it's working fine. But .env key values have to take dynamic

For reference, I have tried:

```html
const myKey = 'TEST_ENV';
const myENV = process.env[myKey];
console.log(myENV); //undefined
```

Comment: Do not try and access `process.env` dynamically. Use `process.env.TEST_ENV` instead since the build will literally look for this and replace it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  Thanks for responding, process.env.TEST_ENV definitely will work..but based on the condition have to pick corresponding .env key name

Comment: Then list all the keys in an object and then use that. `obj = { var1: process.env.var1 }; obj.var1`

Comment: my .env like this                                                                                                   
ENV_A={a:'a.com'}
ENV_B={b:'b.com'}
ENV_c={c:'c.com'}

Comment: Not in the env, do it in the javascript. Leave your .env as `ENV_A=a.com`

Comment: in my .env having multiple objects, each object having multiple keys, for reference i have created two properties here
ENV_A={a:'a.com', a1:'a1.com'}
ENV_B={b:'b.com', b1:'b1.com} 
ENV_c={c:'c.com', c1:'c1.com'}

Comment: Are you saying you've tried that, or you will try it?

Comment: the current structure which I have a single object with multiple keys which is working fine..but planning to change the structure to multiple objects have to create in .env and based on conditions have to pick the respective  object
.env
ENV_A={a:'a.com', a1:'a1.com'} 
ENV_B={b:'b.com', b1:'b1.com}
ENV_c={c:'c.com', c1:'c1.com'}

in js file based on condition have to pick respective env object it should be dynamic

Comment: Is the condition happening at build time or is it client side (in the browser)?

Comment: from API response if I get model property as ENV_A, then have to pick from .env is ENV_A object like others

Comment: Consider using a js file instead of `.env`?

Comment: in the future, if we want add more objects we can add it .env easily instead of finding for the js file...

Comment: Don’t use the env file. It’s not suited for this by default with react.

Answer (score 0):

1. in your root directory create a `.env` file
2. Open .env and declare your enviornment variables

React enforces the prefix `REACT_APP` on every custom variable.
Variable without `REACT_APP` is ignored.

So always create a custom variable like `REACT_APP_CUSTOM_VARIABLE`.

in your case that would be:

```
REACT_APP_MY_KEY = 'TEST_ENV'
```

The way you access env variables is by using `process.env.REACT_APP_MY_KEY` in the corresponding component

Comment: This doesn't help, because the question is about `process.env[keyName]`.

Comment: able to access directly process.env.REACT_APP_MY_KEY values..but in my .env have 10 properties based on the condition have to pick corresponding .env keys